# How to upgrade MySQL Connector/ODBC from 5.1 to 5.2?

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysql-connector

How does one upgrade the MySQL Connector/ODBC from 5.1 to 5.2? When I replace the connection string

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};...
```

with

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Driver};...
```

it does not work and I get

```
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben"
```

(If you happen to know the english error message, please remove this note and add the english error message.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 5.2 version comes in two flavors: ANSI and Unicode, in addition to the version number the name has changed to either:

- `MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver` (recommended)
- `MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver`

See also:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-versions.html